# Unable to mount 1.0 GB volume: Device /dev/sdb is already mounted at `/media/usb0'

Tags: usb, mount

This error message pops up whenever I plug in my USB stick. A similar message appears when I plug in my ereader although my MP3 player opens up normally. I am unable to modify any of the contents on the devices although I can open them and see what is on there.

I'm still new to Ubuntu so would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to see the root cause of the problem. 
You have probably installed the app **usbmount**, which will have broken the USB automounting functionality built into the system. If you have, uninstall usbmount and you will probably find that your problem goes away. The app usbmount is designed for GUI-less systems - mostly servers. Don't try to use it with desktop installations. You will run into exactly these problems.

```
sudo apt-get remove usbmount
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo su
rm -rf /media/usb0
mkdir /media/<user>/usb0
chmod -Rf 777 /media/<user>/usb0
--Plug your usb-stick and run:--
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/<user>/usb0 

Change <user> to Your user-name
```

Comment: After running the second line I got the error message  
  
`rm: cannot remove ‘/media/usb0’: Is a directory`

Comment: You must run rm -rf. Post corrected

Comment: Error after 3rd line this time:  

`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/james/usb0’: File exists`

Comment: Worked for me! However, I ended up doing `chmod -Rf 777 /media`

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and run this command:

```
sudo umount /media/{Your-USB-Name}
```

In my case, it was `usb0`.

Comment: This will only un-mount the device. Add the line for mounting it also

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem on my computer by deleting all the usb directories under /media.  I.E. First umount and remove any USB drives, then:

cd /media

sudo rmdir usb*